# plotly choropleth not drawing any polygons

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, choropleth

I have been following this https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/ tutorial to draw a choropleth map of Australian suburbs.
Using this https://github.com/tonywr71/GeoJson-Data/blob/master/australian-suburbs.geojson as the base geojson data, and then modifying it such that each feature has an 'id' property, which is the postcode for that feature. The final result looks like this: (available at https://github.com/meherGill/geojson_suburbs/blob/main/suburbsModified.geojson)
[image]

The corresponding dataframe for this is
[image]

and the code to draw the map is

```
import plotly.express as px

with open('./data/suburbsModified.geojson') as f:
    jsondata = json.loads(f.read())

fig = px.choropleth(df2, geojson=jsondata, locations='Postal', color='Status', color_continuous_scale="Viridis")
fig.show()
```

But my figure looks like this, a map with nothing drawn on it.
[image]

Why is it not drawing a choropleth map of australian suburbs as defined in the geojson file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- fundamentally your issues are the fact your geojson is problematic.  Viewing on GitHub shows that modified geojson does not overlay Australia
- original geojson shows other issues, a few of the features have no geometry.  Have used **geopandas** to filter this out
- have synthesized `df2` from the geojson so that your code could be used
- approach I would recommend is using source geojson and supplementing postal code in data frame

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# original geojson
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonywr71/GeoJson-Data/master/australian-suburbs.geojson"
# user's geojson
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meherGill/geojson_suburbs/main/suburbsModified.geojson"
fix = True

# get geojson
req = requests.get(url)
jsondata = req.json()

# well there is some invalid geomtry, exclude using geopandas
if fix:
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(jsondata).set_index(
        pd.json_normalize(jsondata["features"])["id"]
    )
    jsondata = gdf.loc[~gdf.geometry.isna()].__geo_interface__

# syntesize data frame
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Postal": pd.json_normalize(req.json()["features"])["id"]}).assign(
    Status=lambda d: np.random.randint(1, 400, len(d))
)

fig = px.choropleth(
    df2,
    geojson=jsondata,
    locations="Postal",
    color="Status",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Ah I see, And is there a way to see what is wrong with my modified geojson? Because my VScode doesn't show any linting errors on it.

Comment: when you open in a browser, GitHub will preview the geojson on a map... how you have generated your geojson you have not stated, possibly you have transposed lat/lon in polygons/geopolygons.  hence reason I recommend leave geojson alone and supplement properties in **pandas**